# Unable to push the generated APK file into the github repository from Android Studio

Tags: android, github, github-for-windows, android-studio-2.0

I have successfully pushed everything to GitHub from Android Studio, except the generated apk file.

Can anyone help me how to push the apk file to the GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2):

You usually don't push any generated code or artifacts into a repository and Github lets you manually upload artifacts for that purpose (check Releases).

Check your [`.gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) file in your project for the line containing the `build` folder. That's usually per default in every project since it's really bad practise putting those into version control.

Comment: Yes Github is uploading the artifacts for me. In those artifacts, I want the apk file to also go as I need that when I need to run the same from Jenkins.I have checked the .gitignore file and removed the build folder, but with no luck.